# case statement not working with ref cursor

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, case

I am writing a stored procedure to retrieve matched file location from a table add_files_tables. I am using case statement with ref cursor to get resultset and then will print filenames. I have created the packages ,but it is giving me empty set always. Where is the problem .

```
create or replace package search_cur as
    type my_cursor is ref cursor;
    function search_File(FILE_NAME varchar2,opt number) return my_cursor;
end search_cur;
/

create or replace package body search_cur as
    function search_File(FILE_NAME varchar2,opt number) return my_cursor is
        ret my_cursor;
    begin
        Case opt
            when 1 THEN
                OPEN ret FOR
                    select file_location
                      from add_files_details
                     where upper(username) like '%'||file_Name||'%'
                ;
                return ret;
            when 2 THEN
                OPEN ret FOR
                    select file_location
                      from add_files_details
                     where upper(EXTENSION) like '%'||file_name||'%'
                ;
                return ret;
            WHEN 3 THEN
                OPEN ret FOR
                    select file_location
                      from add_files_details
                     where upper(UPLOAD_DATE) like '%'||file_name||'%'
                ;
                return ret;
            WHEN 4 THEN
                OPEN ret FOR
                    select file_location
                      from add_files_details
                     where upper(FOLDER_ID) like '%'||file_name||'%';
                return ret;
            when 5 then
                open ret for
                    select file_location
                      from add_files_details
                     where upper(file_name) like '%'||file_name||'%';
                return ret;
        end case;
    end search_file;
end search_cur;
/
```

Comment: Please post a [short, self-contained example](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces your problem. You've posted both too *much* code and too *little*: Too *much*, in that I can't imagine your problem requires all of those cases to be reproducible, and too *little*, in that you haven't posted what would allow it to be reproduced.

Comment: You might want to change your comparisons to convert the input parameter FILE_NAME to upper case before using it since you're converting all the fields to upper case as part of the comparison, e.g. use something like `...where upper(file_name like '%' || UPPER (file_name) || '%'`.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: While posting, i was in hurry , thats why , i posted the code only . I am trying to achieve advanced search functionality via it. Whenever any user chooses by which type ,he wants to search,like by extension or by username ,that will be retrieved as a number and then the name he inputs in the search box. So, we thought of creating a single procedure and giving different outputs for different options.
@Bob, actually i was converting that search_value in java frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name of the parameter so it doesn't conflict with a field  name.  There is a field in your table called `file_name` and the parameter to the routine is `FILE_NAME`.  These are equivalent in the eyes of the PL/SQL compiler, and it's probably guessing wrong as to which one should be used.  Try something like:

```
create or replace package body search_cur as
    function search_File(inp_Search_value varchar2,
                         inp_Opt          number) return my_cursor is
        ret my_cursor;
    begin
        Case inp_Opt 
            when 1 THEN
                OPEN ret FOR
                    select file_location
                      from add_files_details
                     where upper(username) like '%'||UPPER(inp_Search_value ) ||'%'
                ;
                return ret;
            when 2 THEN
                OPEN ret FOR
                    select file_location
                      from add_files_details
                     where upper(EXTENSION) like '%'||UPPER(inp_Search_value )||'%'
                ;
                return ret;
            WHEN 3 THEN
                OPEN ret FOR
                    select file_location
                      from add_files_details
                     where upper(UPLOAD_DATE) like '%'||UPPER(inp_Search_value )||'%'
                ;
                return ret;
            WHEN 4 THEN
                OPEN ret FOR
                    select file_location
                      from add_files_details
                     where upper(FOLDER_ID) like '%'||UPPER(inp_Search_value )||'%';
                return ret;
            when 5 then
                open ret for
                    select file_location
                      from add_files_details
                     where upper(file_name) like '%'||UPPER(inp_Search_value )||'%';
                return ret;
        end case;
    end search_file;
end search_cur;
```

Since the input field is not always a file name it's misleading to call it one - I suggest using a generic sort of name as shown above.  In addition, if you're converting the database fields to upper case it's a good idea to convert the search parameter as well.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: That conflicting name was causing the problem. Silly Mistake by Me .. Thank you for pointing out the solution.